# Making a Sass mixin with optional arguments

Tags: sass

I am writing a mixin like this:

```css
@mixin box-shadow($top, $left, $blur, $color, $inset:"") {
    -webkit-box-shadow: $top $left $blur $color $inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: $top $left $blur $color $inset;
    box-shadow: $top $left $blur $color $inset;
}
```

When called what I really want is that if no `$inset` value is passed, nothing is output, rather than it compiling to something like this:

```css
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #555555 "";
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #555555 "";
box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #555555 "";
```

How do I rewrite the mixin so that if there is no value of `$inset` passed, nothing is output?

Comment: It's a shame that SASS doesn't have a `blank` or `nil` value.

Comment: Btw, while looking at a different SASS limitation, I came across a nice way to get rid of the quotes in these situations. I added an answer for it.

Comment: Now in 2015 you can just use `null` in order to skip attr/prop.
`ie @include box-shadow($top, $left, $blur, $color, null)`

Answer (score 284, accepted):

### A DRY'r Way of Doing It

*And, generally, a neat trick to remove the quotes.*

```css
@mixin box-shadow($top, $left, $blur, $color, $inset:"") {
  -webkit-box-shadow: $top $left $blur $color #{$inset};
  -moz-box-shadow:    $top $left $blur $color #{$inset};
  box-shadow:         $top $left $blur $color #{$inset};
}
```

#### SASS Version 3+, you can use `unquote()`:

```css
@mixin box-shadow($top, $left, $blur, $color, $inset:"") {
  -webkit-box-shadow: $top $left $blur $color unquote($inset);
  -moz-box-shadow:    $top $left $blur $color unquote($inset);
  box-shadow:         $top $left $blur $color unquote($inset);
}
```

*Picked this up over here: [pass a list to a mixin as a single argument with SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517941/pass-a-list-to-a-mixin-as-a-single-argument-with-sass/9960372#9960372)*

Comment: As Bob Sammers points out, in newer version of SASS you can also use the unquote() method instead of #{} to remove the quotes. Cheers.

Comment: the most simple way is to use `null` for default value of optional parameters instead of `""`, and they will not be rendered in output! `@mixin box-shadow($top, $left,... , $inset:null) {}`

Comment: @S.Serpooshan I'm curious what version this was added in. This certainly wasn't supported back in 2012.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter even docs for it are harder to find https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/null but they don't mention any compatibility like e.g. for "Configuring Modules", what I find interesting is it seems to only remove property line when the variable is used directly as the property value (but not when passed along) I created a showcase - https://jsfiddle.net/eqw3oxcv/

Answer (score 93):

## **A so much better DRY way**

is to pass `$args...` to the `@mixin`.
That way, no matter how many `$args` you will pass.
In the `@input` call, you can pass all args needed. 
Like so:

```
@mixin box-shadow($args...) {
  -webkit-box-shadow: $args;
  -moz-box-shadow: $args;
  box-shadow: $args;
}
```

And now you can reuse your box-shadow in every class you want by passing all needed args:

```
.my-box-shadow {
  @include box-shadow(2px 2px 5px #555, inset 0 0 0);
}
```

Comment: That's good to know but often times it's more clear to indicate what arguments a `mixin` is expecting, like `$top`, `$left`, `$blur`, etc. Variable arguments, like you've shown, are great for ultimate flexibility, though.

Comment: Thanks, dude it helps me a lot

Comment: This is too generic. Especially if you only want to expose some values of a CSS property. For example: animation: spin $duration $timingFunction infinite.

Answer (score 54):

Sass supports `@if` statements. (See the [documentation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#control_directives).)

You could write your mixin like this:

```
@mixin box-shadow($top, $left, $blur, $color, $inset:"") {
  @if $inset != "" {
    -webkit-box-shadow:$top $left $blur $color $inset;
    -moz-box-shadow:$top $left $blur $color $inset;
    box-shadow:$top $left $blur $color $inset;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not useful here, only the `inset` part must be excluded when it is null, not all box-shadow properties

Comment: @S.Serpooshan Just add an `else` and include all non-inset properties inside.

Comment: @mbomb007 i know, i just report a problem with this solution. And other answers provided above are absolutely better.

Answer (score 29):

You can put the property with null as a default value and if you don't pass the parameter it will not be interpreted.

```
@mixin box-shadow($top, $left, $blur, $color, $inset:null) {
  -webkit-box-shadow: $top $left $blur $color $inset;
  -moz-box-shadow:    $top $left $blur $color $inset;
  box-shadow:         $top $left $blur $color $inset;
}
```

This means you can write the include statement like this.

```
@include box-shadow($top, $left, $blur, $color);
```

Instead of writing it like this.

```
@include box-shadow($top, $left, $blur, $color, null);
```

As shown in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23565388/4601149)

Comment: This answer offers nothing new over the existing answers (see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23565388/1652962)

Comment: @cimmanon On the contrary, this provides extra utility as you can then write the import as `@include box-shadow($top, $left, $blur, $color);` instead of `@include box-shadow($top, $left, $blur, $color, null);`. Therefore this answer is so much more benificial.

Comment: @Dan Actually you lose readability doing it that way, so arguably it's *less* beneficial than the answer it's derived from.

Comment: @TylerH That is true

Answer (score 14):

Old question, I know, but I think this is still relevant. Arguably, a clearer way of doing this is to use the unquote() function (which SASS has had since version 3.0.0):

```
@mixin box-shadow($top, $left, $blur, $color, $inset:"") {
  -webkit-box-shadow: $top $left $blur $color unquote($inset);
  -moz-box-shadow: $top $left $blur $color unquote($inset);
  box-shadow: $top $left $blur $color unquote($inset);
}
```

This is roughly equivalent to Josh's answer, but I think the explicitly named function is less obfuscated than the string interpolation syntax.

Answer (score 14):

I know its not exactly the answer you were searching for but you could pass `"null"` as last argument  when `@include box-shadow` mixin, like this `@include box-shadow(12px, 14px, 2px, green, null);` Now, if that argument is only one in that property than that property (and its (default) value) won't get compiled. If there are two or more args on that "line" only ones that you nulled won't get compiled (your case).

CSS output is exactly as you wanted it, but you have to write your `null`s :)

```
  @include box-shadow(12px, 14px, 2px, green, null);

  // compiles to ...

  -webkit-box-shadow: 12px 14px 2px green;  
  -moz-box-shadow: 12px 14px 2px green;  
  box-shadow: 12px 14px 2px green;
```

Comment: Definitely my favourite way to do this keeps everything simple to read and understand for when you have to come back to a script. thnx Drops.

Answer (score 8):

here is the solution i use, with notes below:

```
@mixin transition($trans...) {
  @if length($trans) < 1 {
    $trans: all .15s ease-out;
  }
  -moz-transition: $trans;
  -ms-transition: $trans;
  -webkit-transition: $trans;
  transition: $trans;
}

.use-this {
  @include transition;
}

.use-this-2 {
  @include transition(all 1s ease-out, color 2s ease-in);
}
```

- prefer passing property values as native css to stay close to "the tongue"
- allow passing variable number of arguments
- define a default value for laziness

Comment: How does this add anything over the existing answers (namely: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28072864/1652962)?

Comment: He explained how to tell if more than one argument is passed to the function and if so, change the output. The other answer did not.

Comment: sometimes, you want to define a global behaviour. for example, animation transitions where you generally want to have a very uniform experience and don't want to risk "creative developer discretion" when it comes to deciding what to do.


this defines a default that can be overridden but often won't be because of the more compact syntax when not passing arguments.


you can also change the global behaviour in a single place this way.

Answer (score 6):

## **Even DRYer way!**

```
@mixin box-shadow($args...) {
  @each $pre in -webkit-, -moz-, -ms-, -o- {
    #{$pre + box-shadow}: $args;
  } 
  #{box-shadow}: #{$args};
}
```

And now you can reuse your box-shadow even smarter:

```
.myShadow {
  @include box-shadow(2px 2px 5px #555, inset 0 0 0);
}
```

Comment: Just a note - as readable as this is and I do acknowledge that, this is where one should draw the line between DRY code and *readability/maintainability*.

Comment: I agree, to increase _readability/maintainability_ I would create a "browser list" to reuse in other mixins. This could also pretty easy be assembled to other css properties, that can be executed with a set of dry mixins. [This article](https://alistapart.com/article/dry-ing-out-your-sass-mixins) from 2014 is still great example.

Comment: a good one, impressive way to handle multi-browser support.

Answer (score 3):

With sass@3.4.9 :

```
// declare
@mixin button( $bgcolor:blue ){
    background:$bgcolor;
}
```

and use without value, button will be blue

```
//use
.my_button{
    @include button();
}
```

and with value, button will be red

```
//use
.my_button{
    @include button( red );
}
```

works with hexa too

Comment: How does this add anything over the existing answers?

Answer (score 2):

```
@mixin box-shadow($left: 0, $top: 0, $blur: 6px, $color: hsla(0,0%,0%,0.25), $inset: false) {
    @if $inset {
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset $left $top $blur $color;
        -moz-box-shadow: inset $left $top $blur $color;
        box-shadow: inset $left $top $blur $color;
    } @else {
        -webkit-box-shadow: $left $top $blur $color;
        -moz-box-shadow: $left $top $blur $color;
        box-shadow: $left $top $blur $color;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is arguably worse than all of the other answers, due to its verbosity.  Also, its close enough to [one of the other answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3535205/1652962) to count as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

## Super simple way

Just add a default value of `none` to $inset - so

```
@mixin box-shadow($top, $left, $blur, $color, $inset: none) { ....
```

Now when no $inset is passed nothing will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You can always assign null to your optional arguments. Here is a simple fix

```
@mixin box-shadow($top, $left, $blur, $color, $inset:null) { //assigning null to inset value makes it optional
    -webkit-box-shadow: $top $left $blur $color $inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: $top $left $blur $color $inset;
    box-shadow: $top $left $blur $color $inset;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am new to css compilers, hope this helps,

```
        @mixin positionStyle($params...){

            $temp:nth($params,1);
            @if $temp != null{
            position:$temp;
            }

             $temp:nth($params,2);
            @if $temp != null{
            top:$temp;
            }

             $temp:nth($params,3);
            @if $temp != null{
            right:$temp;
            }

             $temp:nth($params,4);
            @if $temp != null{
            bottom:$temp;
            }

            $temp:nth($params,5);
            @if $temp != null{
            left:$temp;
            }

    .someClass{
    @include positionStyle(absolute,30px,5px,null,null);
    }

//output

.someClass{
position:absolute;
 top: 30px;
 right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: How does this add anything over the existing answers?