# Adding !important using a Compass Mixin

Tags: compass-sass

If I'm using compass for CSS and use a function or mixin like:

```
   @include background-image(linear-gradient(#a3cce0, #fff));
```

is there any easy way to have compass add !important to every line it generates?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not possible with Compass. There is no direct fix for this, but you could copy the mixin internals and add `!important` somewhere yourself. It's not ideal, but there is no other option for it yet.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**UPDATE**: new versions of sass support this syntax now:

```
@include border-radius(5px !important);
```

Just do this (as noted in @naoufal answer).

--- old answer ---

You can not use !important with compass mixings, but the culprit is not compass, you should blame **sass** for this.

```
@include border-radius(5px) !important; #=> SASS Syntax Error
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `@include border-radius(5px !important);` which also does not work. The reason for this would be because the `5px` will show up as the value of each rule, so the !important needs to also show up next to the value of each rule.

Comment: @ProLoser I just tried `@include border-radius(5px !important);` and it works fine. Maybe they've fixed this since your comment though. Down-vote this answer (though it may have been right at the time).

Answer (score 89):

You can include it inside the mixin like so:

```
@include border-radius(5px !important);
```

Compass will output the following:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 5px !important;
-moz-border-radius: 5px !important;
-ms-border-radius: 5px !important;
-o-border-radius: 5px !important;
border-radius: 5px !important;
```

Comment: As !important works with Compass (at least it does now), this should really be the best answer.

Comment: This works for me using (at present latest) version of compass 0.12.2

Comment: This isn't really a great approach as you may not want to have the !important on every single call of the mixin.

Comment: @OliverBenns If that were the case, you wouldn't benefit from using a mixin in the first place.

Comment: This will not work when using mixins that change the values of the args. Like @opacity() for example.

Answer (score 11):

Actually you can use a `@function` to handle the `!important` while keeping the flexibility of the mixing itself. For example:

```
@function is-important($important){
  @return #{if($important, '!important', '')};
}

// by default we don't want the !important at the end
@mixin button-primary($important: false) {
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #fff is-important($important);
  color: #000 is-important($important);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: And so you can include like this : @include quiz-button-arrow(true); Thank you really much for this!

Answer (score 7):

Just spent hours figuring this out but there is a quick trick you can do. At the top of your SASS file add the following:

```
$i: unquote("!important");
```

in your style do the following:

```
color: #CCCCCC $i;
```

output is:

```
color: #CCCCCC !important;
```

full sample:

```
$i: unquote("!important");

.some-style {
    color: white $i;
}
```

output:

```
.some-style {
    color: white !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I used this idea in Koala preprocessor, I only had to use the variable this way:
`... color: white #{$i}; ..."

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing this. Have been looking for this since whole day.

Answer (score 4):

This question came up in my search for a similar problem, it's spot on but I just wanted to add that [Making a Sass mixin with optional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525007/making-a-sass-mixin-with-optional-arguments) was another possible approach that I found useful.

Replace `inset` with `important` and pass `!important` in when you need it.

Comment: You get the +1 for helping me get rid of the errors in my IDE (webstorm). It works without the quotes as mentioned by naoufal above, but I hate having the "errors" in my project. I'm gonna submit a bug report to JetBrains for this.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem last time and I overrided the compass style with a stronger selector. I just added an ID on my html element

```
span { @include border-radius(5px);}

span#no-radius { @include border-radius(0px); } // override
```

Comment: Nice and elegant solution.

Comment: There shouldn't be an id called `no-radius`. This is more of an hackish solution.