# Adding `!important` to a mixin

Tags: css, sass

I want to add `!important` to a mixin. I tried both the following ways, and they return an error:

```
@include linear-gradient(hsl(68%, 94%, 90%), hsl(68%, 90%, 80%)); !important

@include linear-gradient(hsl(68%, 94%, 90%), hsl(68%, 90%, 80%)) !important;
```

Is there a way to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use !important on a Mixin.

it will end up giving you a SASS syntax error.

See [this question for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115959/adding-important-using-a-compass-mixin)

Answer (score 8):

For some situations, I use a optional parameter named `$important` which I can pass in `true`.

Example:

```
my-mixin($important: true);
```

It would look something like that, with a helper function to avoid repetition on the properties that I have to toggle `important`:

```
@function if-important($important){
  @return #{if($important, '!important', '')};
}

@mixin my-mixin($important: false) {
  border-radius: 0; //whatever
  border: 1px solid #ccc if-important($important);
  background-color: #fff if-important($important);
  color: #000 if-important($important);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

!important cannot be used in a mixin. Refer the following links.

[Adding !important using a Compass Mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115959/adding-important-using-a-compass-mixin)

https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/547

):

Comment: Thanks, the github discussion is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing it as a parameter:

```
@mixin anim($params...){

  $values: null;

  @for $i from 0 to length($params) {

    @debug #{nth($params, $i + 1)};

    @if '#{nth($params, $i + 1)}' != '!important' {
      $values: #{nth($params, $i + 1)} $animation__time $animation__easing, $values;
    }
  }
  @if '#{nth($params, length($params))}' != '!important' {
    transition: $values;
  }
  @else {
    transition: $values !important;
  }

}
```

Usage:

```
@include anim(background-color, color, !important);
```