# Converting LESS Mixins with !important to SCSS

Tags: css, sass, less

I am new to SCSS, but I hit a snag while converting this LESS code.

**In Less**

```
.white {background: #fff} 

.color {.white() !important}
```

produces

```
.white {background: #fff}

.color {background: #fff !important}
```

I am trying to replicate the behaviour in SCSS but so far all my tries have been getting syntax error.

The best I came up with in my google searches was this: [Adding !important using a Compass Mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115959/adding-important-using-a-compass-mixin), however, it only seems to work with mixins that have parameters. My class/mixin does not have any.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [placeholder selectors](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/understanding-placeholder-selectors):

```
%white{
    background: #fff !important;
}

.color{
    @extend %white;
}
```

It may not be a mixin, but `%white` wouldn't be added to the CSS until it has been extended.