# Passing an "empty" argument to a SASS mixin so that the default argument gets used

Tags: css, sass

Consider the following two mixins:

```
@mixin padding($v: 8px)
  padding: $v - 3 $v $v - 3 $v

@mixin button($padding: "")
  @include padding($padding)
  @include border-radius
  border: 1px solid black
```

I can call `@include padding` without an argument, and the default `8px` gets used, no problem. But how can I call the `button` mixin and still have the default value get used in the `padding` mixin? If I simply call `@include button` without an argument, the `button` mixin still seems to pass some kind of argument to `padding` (which `padding` inevitably interprets as 0, thus not adding any padding). Based on [Making a Sass mixin with optional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525007/making-a-sass-mixin-with-optional-arguments), I tried modifying the `button` mixin to have

`@include padding(unquote($padding))`

but that had no effect -- `padding` still seemed to interpret the argument as being 0, rather than there being no argument and thus using its default value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is typically solved by setting the default arguments for both mixins to be the same value.  You may want to use a global variable for this purpose:

```
$default-padding: 8px

@mixin padding($v: $default-padding)
  padding: $v - 3 $v $v - 3 $v

@mixin button($padding: $default-padding)
  @include padding($padding)
  @include border-radius
  border: 1px solid black
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the solution I'm currently going with.