# Giving default arguments to mixins when there is more than one variable

Tags: sass

I am trying to make a  `@mixin` where I want to give a default value to the first variable but not to the second variable.

```
@mixin myCoolFont($color:purple, $size) {
    color: $color;
    font-size: $size;
}
```

Now when I call that mixin I do something like this:

```
p {
    @include myCoolFont(white, 63px)
}
```

When compiling it outputs an error that says `$size must come before any other arguments.`

Please, tell me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you want to happen, when you don't set the second variable?

Comment: In my opinion, from all the information that you've given, that's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525007/making-a-sass-mixin-with-optional-arguments?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You just do as error says, it will work, simple change order of arguments so that last argument(s) are those with default values. In your case:

```
@mixin myCoolFont($size, $color:purple) {
  color: $color;
  font-size: $size;
}


p {
  @include myCoolFont(63px, white)
}
```