# How can I handle a variable number of parameters in mixins?

Tags: css, sass

I have a mixin for a gradient that currently takes two colors:

```
@mixin gradient($color-start, $color-end) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, $color-start 0%, $color-end 100%);
}
```

which I use everywhere like so

```
.my-gradient {
  @include gradient(blue, yellow)
}
```

but now I'd like to modify the mixin (or convert it to a function) that can take two **or** three parameters for the gradient.

something like (pseudo code):

```
@mixin gradient($color-start, $color-end, $color-center) {
  ...if $color-center param exists...
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, $color-start 0%, $color-center 50%, $color-end 100%);
  ...if $color-center param does not exist...
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, $color-start 0%, $color-end 100%);
}
```

I'm not sure of the best way to handle this condition.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/9960403/5561605

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write if-else clauses in your mixin!

```
@mixin gradient($color-start, $color-end, $color-center:null) {
  @if($color-center){
       background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, $color-start 0%, $color-center 50%, $color-end 100%);  
  }@else{
       background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, $color-start 0%, $color-end 100%);    
  }

}

.test_1{
  @include gradient(#000, #111);
}

.test_2{
  @include gradient(#111,#222,#333);
}
```

outputs:

```
.test_1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #000 0%, #111 100%);
}

.test_2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #111 0%, #333 50%, #222 100%);
}
```

note that i set the parameter value of `$color-center`to `null` otherwise there would be an error if you only pass 2 arguments