# What's the SASS equivalent of Javascript's "var x = y || z"?

Tags: javascript, sass

Javascript

> var x = y || z  (logical-or operator)

```
x = y if y is not falsy, otherwise z
```

**What's the SASS/SCSS equivalent of Javascript's "var x = y || z"?**

Comment: A quick google search for **"sass assign default value to variable if undefined"** lead me to the official docs about default variables: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525007/making-a-sass-mixin-with-optional-arguments

Comment: Your explanation of `var x = y || z` is not entirely correct. `y` may be defined as a falsy value, and in that case the value in `z` will end up in `x`. Also, if `y` is not defined your code will encounter a Reference Error.

Comment: @edo.n good point. I will update the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```scss
$x = if(variable-exists('y'), $y, $z);`
```

[Docs for variable-exists](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/meta#variable-exists)

Answer (score 3):

The `!default` flag, will have this variable skipped, if it already exists.

For example:

```
$var: foo;
$var: bar !default;

@debug $var; // foo
```

And:

```
$var: bar !default;

@debug $var; // bar
```

**Update:** since you clarified your question, this might be a better approach:

```
@function return($x, $y) {
  @return if(($x != false), $x, $y);
}

@debug return("foo", "bar"); // "foo"
@debug return (false, "bar"); // "bar
```

Answer (score 0):

## Double-pipe Operator

### This construct is called "double-pipe operator" in JavaScript, and helps a lot in writing readable and clean code.

But I don't think SASS have something like it, sadly. The closest you can get to it is by using default values with the `!default` tag or the @if and @else flow controls.

Comment: It is the "Logical OR" operator in Javascript; it's written as a double-pipe but it is not _called_ the "double-pipe" operator. It's _called_ the logical-or operator.